# Remove selected item from the ng-autocomplete dropdown in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using ng-autocomplete dropdown in angular 8. I want to remove selected item from the dropdown list and as well as get back in the dropdown once the selected item is removed.

Here is my code

autocomplete.component.html:

```
  <ng-autocomplete 
                   formControlName="skillSet" 
                  [searchKeyword]="keyword" 
                  (selected)="selectEvent($event)"
                  (inputChanged)="getInput($event)"
                  [data]="skillArray"
                  [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate">
                  </ng-autocomplete>
    
                  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
                   <a [innerHTML]="item.name" *ngIf="checkItemExists(item.name)"></a>
                  </ng-template>
```

Component.ts:

```
  checkItemExists(value: any) {
    return this.skillListArray.filter((x: any) => x.name === value).length === 0;
  }
```

**This is working fine but i need to do this filter in html only with (ngIf) as i have read somewhere that going from html to component will make slow your application.**

Comment: Which library are you using for ng-autocomplete. Please create a minimal reproduction on stackblitz

Comment: i am using angular-ng-autocomplete library.

Answer (score 0):

In template:

```
(selected)='selectEvent($event)'
```

On component:

```
 selectEvent(item) {
    let index = this.data.indexOf(item);
    if(index !== -1) {
      this.data.splice(index, 1);
      // add the previously removed item to the data (if another item was selected before)
      if(this.previousItem){
        this.data.push(this.previousItem);
      }
      this.previousItem = item;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will work when we are selecting or selected event fires. i want to filter dropdown while in edit mode as well. In edit mode some dropdown values are preselected for the user and those needs to be filtered out from the dropdown on page load only.